# Can msbuild create an .appxbundle for multiple platforms?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, windows-store-apps, windows-10, appx

I'm trying to build an .appxbundle for my Windows 10 UWP Store app using msbuild that contains x86, x64, and ARM platforms. I can do this from VS2015 RTM using the Create App Pacakges wizard, but I get errors when I use msbuild. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

My command line:

```
msbuild HelloWorld.csproj /p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always
```

Errors I'm getting:

```
"E:\TestApps\HelloWorld.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(_CreateBundle target) ->
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3631,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "E:\TestApps\bin\x64\Release\HelloWorld_1.0.4.0_x64.appx" because it was not found. [E:\TestApps\HelloWorld.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3631,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "E:\TestApps\bin\ARM\Release\HelloWorld_1.0.4.0_ARM.appx" because it was not found. [E:\TestApps\HelloWorld.csproj]
```

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 3):

Try to specify AppxBundlePlatforms parameter in your project file, something like: `<AppxBundlePlatforms>x86|x64|arm</AppxBundlePlatforms>.`

This should work with VS2015.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34362297/540639) answer worked for me. I copy it here for not just leaving the link-only answer.

```
MSBuild mysolution.sln  /p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM"
```

Comment: I was looking for how to do this in Azure DevOps, this was the correct answer