# Creating app package from command line using msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, uwp

I can create App Packages from Visual Studio 2013 using the wizard.

[image]

The result file is *MyProject_Win8_1.1.1.3_x86_x64_arm_bundle.appxupload*, which is fine!

I can use the following command to build an *.appxupload* file for any platform.

```
msbuild mysolution.sln /property:Configuration="Release" /t:"myproject_Win8" /p:Platform="ARM" /m:4 /t:"Publish"
```

which leads to generation of *MyProject_Win8_1.1.1.3_ARM.appxupload*

How can I tell *msbuild* to build all 3 platforms I need and generate one *.appxupload* file, which will contain them all?

Comment: Possible duplicate if you're looking for a solution for VS2015: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469750/can-msbuild-create-an-appxbundle-for-multiple-platforms

Comment: @sibbl: It's not a duplicate. I use VS2013 and I've got <AppxBundlePlatforms>x86|x64|arm</AppxBundlePlatforms> line in my project file, but it doesn't help

Comment: The version is added automatically when use msbuild command ? or it was set as parameter somewhere ?

Comment: @deko How did you set the versioning number via a command ("/p:...")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this command line :

```
MSBuild mysolution.sln  /p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM"
```

Comment: The first line works fine!
The secons line fails with an error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release|ARM|x86|x64" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.
Please leave the firstline only and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: For me, running this produces an appxbundle, but no appxupload. Did that work for you @deko ? (might be that I'm using VS15 instead of 13?)